# D3 zoomable sunburst order children

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is my basic version of the sunburst zoomable chart.

As you can see from the picture the data is not in any particular order. I am hoping to be able t o order the children as the circle goes round by the name that of which is attached in the element itself.

[image: my graph]

I have ordered the json data so that the first level of children should be: Amy, Bender, Chris Audience, Fry, etc. but this is not helping.

I forked another persons example from jsFiddle and modified it slightly just to show off my problem. it can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/0ugvtmco/1/

```
var width = 500,
    height = 500,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

var y = d3.scale.sqrt()
    .range([0, radius]);

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + (height / 2 + 10) + ") rotate(-90 0 0)");

var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .value(function (d) {
    return d.size;
});

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function (d) {
    return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x)));
})
    .endAngle(function (d) {
    return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x + d.dx)));
})
    .innerRadius(function (d) {
    return Math.max(0, y(d.y));
})
    .outerRadius(function (d) {
    return Math.max(0, y(d.y + d.dy));
});

//d3.json("/d/4063550/flare.json", function(error, root) {
var root =  getData();

var g = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(partition.nodes(root))
    .enter().append("g");

var path = g.append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style("fill", function (d) {
        return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name);
    })
    .on("click", click);

//.append("text")
var text = g.append("text")
    .attr("x", function (d) {
    return y(d.y);
})
    .attr("dx", "6") // margin
.attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align
.attr("transform", function (d) {
    return "rotate(" + computeTextRotation(d) + ")";
})
.text(function (d) {
    return d.name;
})
.style("fill","white");

function computeTextRotation(d) {
    var angle = x(d.x + d.dx / 2) - Math.PI / 2;
    return angle / Math.PI * 180;
}

//text.attr("transform", function (d) {
//    return "rotate(" + computeTextRotation(d) + ")";
//});



/*
var label = g.append("rect")
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x) })
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y) })
.attr("width", function(d) { return 100 })
.attr("height", function(d) { return 100 })
.attr("transform", function (d) {
    return "rotate(" + computeTextRotation(d) + ")";
})
.attr("style", "fill:blue;stroke:pink;stroke-width:5;fill-opacity:0.1;stroke-opacity:0.9");
*/

function click(d) {
    // fade out all text elements
    if(d.size !== undefined) {
        d.size += 100;
    };
    text.transition().attr("opacity", 0);

    path.transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attrTween("d", arcTween(d))
        .each("end", function (e, i) {
        // check if the animated element's data e lies within the visible angle span given in d
        if (e.x >= d.x && e.x < (d.x + d.dx)) {
            // get a selection of the associated text element
            var arcText = d3.select(this.parentNode).select("text");
            // fade in the text element and recalculate positions
            arcText.transition().duration(750)
                .attr("opacity", 1)
                .attr("transform", function () {
                return "rotate(" + computeTextRotation(e) + ")"
            })
                .attr("x", function (d) {
                return y(d.y);
            });
        }
    });
} //});

// Word wrap!
var insertLinebreaks = function (t, d, width) {
    alert(0)
    var el = d3.select(t);
    var p = d3.select(t.parentNode);
    p.append("g")
    .attr("x", function (d) {
    return y(d.y);
})
//    .attr("dx", "6") // margin
//.attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align
.attr("transform", function (d) {
    return "rotate(" + computeTextRotation(d) + ")";
})
//p
    .append("foreignObject")
        .attr('x', -width/2)
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", 200)
      .append("xhtml:p")
        .attr('style','word-wrap: break-word; text-align:center;')
        .html(d.name);    
    alert(1)
    el.remove();
    alert(2)
};

//g.selectAll("text")
//    .each(function(d,i){ insertLinebreaks(this, d, 50 ); });


d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");

// Interpolate the scales!
function arcTween(d) {
    var xd = d3.interpolate(x.domain(), [d.x, d.x + d.dx]),
        yd = d3.interpolate(y.domain(), [d.y, 1]),
        yr = d3.interpolate(y.range(), [d.y ? 20 : 0, radius]);
    return function (d, i) {
        return i ? function (t) {
            return arc(d);
        } : function (t) {
            x.domain(xd(t));
            y.domain(yd(t)).range(yr(t));
            return arc(d);
        };
    };
}

function getData() {
    return {
    "name": "Main", "isMain":"true", "systemName": "Main/Home",
"children": [

{"name": "Amy","isMain":"false", "systemName": "Amy/Home",
"children": [

{"name": "Amy 1","isMain":"false", "systemName": "Amy-1/Home",
"children": [

{"name": "amy 1.1","isMain":"false", "systemName": "amy-1-1/Home", "size": 100}]

}]

},
{"name": "Bender","isMain":"false", "systemName": "Bender/Home",
"children": [

{"name": "bender 1","isMain":"false", "systemName": "bender-1/Home",
"children": [

{"name": "bender 1.1","isMain":"false", "systemName": "bender-1-1/Home", "size": 100}]

}]

},
{"name": "Chris Audience","isMain":"false", "systemName": "ChrisAudience/Home",
"children": [

{"name": "TestAudience","isMain":"false", "systemName": "TestAudience/Home", "size": 100},
{"name": "TestAudience2","isMain":"false", "systemName": "TestAudience2/Home", "size": 100}]

},
{"name": "Fry","isMain":"false", "systemName": "Fry/Home",
"children": [

{"name": "Fry 1","isMain":"false", "systemName": "Fry-1/Home",
"children": [

{"name": "Fry 1.1","isMain":"false", "systemName": "Fry-1-1/Home", "size": 100}]

}]

},
{"name": "Hermes","isMain":"false", "systemName": "Hermes/Home", "size": 100},
{"name": "John Audience","isMain":"false", "systemName": "JohnAudience/Home",
"children": [

{"name": "Ben","isMain":"false", "systemName": "Ben/Home",
"children": [

{"name": "Obiwan","isMain":"false", "systemName": "Obiwan/Home", "size": 100}]

},
{"name": "Luke","isMain":"false", "systemName": "Luke/Home",
"children": [

{"name": "Skywalker","isMain":"false", "systemName": "Skywalker/Home", "size": 100}]

},
{"name": "Peter","isMain":"false", "systemName": "Peter/Home",
"children": [

{"name": "Parker","isMain":"false", "systemName": "Parker/Home", "size": 100},
{"name": "Rasputen","isMain":"false", "systemName": "Rasputen/Home", "size": 100}]

}]

},
{"name": "Leela","isMain":"false", "systemName": "Leela/Home", "size": 100},
{"name": "Not Merica","isMain":"false", "systemName": "NotMerica/Home",
"children": [

{"name": "Europe","isMain":"false", "systemName": "Europe/Home",
"children": [

{"name": "France","isMain":"false", "systemName": "France/Home", "size": 100}]

}]

},
{"name": "Professor","isMain":"false", "systemName": "Professor/Home", "size": 100},
{"name": "Vlad Audience","isMain":"false", "systemName": "Vlad-Audience/Home",
"children": [

{"name": "vlad 1","isMain":"false", "systemName": "vlad-1/Home",
"children": [

{"name": "vlad 1.1","isMain":"false", "systemName": "vlad-1-1/Home", "size": 100}]

}]

},
{"name": "Why Not Zoidberg Audience","isMain":"false", "systemName": "WhyNotZoidbergAudience/Home",
"children": [

{"name": "Zoidberg 1","isMain":"false", "systemName": "Zoidberg-1/Home",
"children": [

{"name": "Zoidberg 1.1","isMain":"false", "systemName": "Zoidberg-1-1/Home", "size": 100}]

}]

},
{"name": "Zap","isMain":"false", "systemName": "Zap/Home",
"children": [

{"name": "Zap 1","isMain":"false", "systemName": "Zap1/Home",
"children": [

{"name": "Zap 1.1","isMain":"false", "systemName": "Zap-1-1/Home", "size": 100}]

}]

}]

};
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

thanks!

[edit - added jsFiddle example]

Comment: Can you add a working example (JSFiddle or similar?)

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer and for anyone else who runs into this I had to change the partition variable to this

```
var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .sort(function(a, b) { return d3.ascending(a.name, b.name); })
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; });
```

the sort in ther eis what will add in the ordering which I was looking for.